# pandas dataframe group by max on one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group by the 'keyword' column and get the characteristic with the larger number of records.

Let's consider the pandas df:

```
pd.DataFrame([['a', 'A'], ['b', 'A'], ['a', 'B'], ['b', 'B'], ['a', 'A'], ['c', 'B']], columns=['Keywords', 'Char'])
```

For the keyword a the characteristic A is the most frequent, for the keyword b either A or B are ok, for the keyword c, B is the most frequent.

In my case I have 10000 keywords and 3 characteristics. I want to have as a return a pd.Series with the keyword as an index and the most frequent characteristic as value or a dictionary with keyword as key and the most frequent characteristic as value.

I tried grouping my keywords and characteristics and count the rows as following:

```
res = frame.groupby(['Keywords', 'Char']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'records'})
```

But I don't know how to get the characteristic corresponding to the maximum.

Expected output (any of this is ok):

```
pd.Series(data=['A', 'A', 'B'], index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

or

```
pd.Series(data=['A', 'B', 'B'], index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

or

```
{'a':'A', 'b':'A', 'c':'B'}
```

or

```
{'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'B'}
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample input data?

Comment: I added right now. Series or dict, both are fine for me. And for the keyword 'b', where the number of occurrences is equal, any answer is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) in lambda function per groups by `Keywords` and return first value of index. Idea of solution is use `value_counts` because sorting values by default by counts:

```
res = frame.groupby('Keywords')['Char'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
print (res)
Keywords
a    A
b    B
c    B
Name: Char, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry for asking dummy question sir, I tried googling but couldn't understand it, could you please do explain use of `.index[0]` I tried with `.index[1]` but it is giving error at that time.